# Copy column from excel

Tags: python, excel, xlsx

I would like to copy some column in a .xlsx file and save it to another file. I tried a lot of thing but they didn't work because of the merged cells. Is there any way to do that correctly?

[image]

I have this and i want to copy that to a new .xlsx file. I have bunch of these and the lenght of the rows are not the same.

Comment: Yes. There is certainly a correct way. But if you want to know how, you will have to add enough information to your question for others to understand where the problem is. You  should read again what a [mre] is...

Comment: Updated, sorry for the bad expression <3

Comment: What have your tried and what is the exact problem in the sense what are the expected and obtained results? I know what are merged cells but I cannot guess what you want to do with them...

Comment: I just want to copy this to a new file, i'm writing a program to my boss but i lost at this part.

Comment: Different tools can be used here, but I still cannot understand exactly what you want. If you want to be able to process the file on a system with no installed Excel application, openpyxl or the pair xlrd xlwr could help. If you want an *exact* copy of some columns on a Windows system having Excel automation through pywin32 will probably give the best results. I could do some tests on my own system, provided you show an example of the input (make sure it can be copy-pasted, so no image please), the expected output, and what you only could get.

Answer (score 0):

```
df[['column1','column2']].to_excel('newfile.xlsx', index = False)
```

but if you don't answer please clarify your question

Comment: My expression was bad, i updated, sorry for it <3